Create an Azure apim with custom domain and certificate in Azure KeyVault
How could I create a new API manager, then assign a role to access certificates of Azure Key Vault and create the hostnameConfigurations with the certification source inside Azure Key Vault.
I've tried something like this below but then I got next error message:

Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/<apimname> at line '1' and column '2581' is defined multiple times in a template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-resources for usage details.'.

resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: variables.resources.apim.name
  sku: variables.resources.apim.sku
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: variables.resources.apim.publisher.email
    publisherName: variables.resources.apim.publisher.name
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: variables.resources.keyVault.name
}

resource apiKeyVaultRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  scope: keyVault
  name: guid(keyVault.id, apim.id, variables.rbac.keyVaultCertificateUser)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
      'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',
      variables.rbac.keyVaultCertificateUser
    )
    principalId: apim.identity.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}

resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: variables.resources.apim.name
  sku: variables.resources.apim.sku
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: variables.resources.apim.publisher.email
    publisherName: variables.resources.apim.publisher.name
    hostnameConfigurations: [
      {
        type: 'Proxy'
        hostName: variables.resources.apim.hostName
        certificateSource: 'KeyVault'
        defaultSslBinding: true
        keyVaultId: 'https://${variables.resources.keyVault.name}${az.environment().suffixes.keyvaultDns}/secrets/savaco-dns'
      }
    ]
  }
}


Is there any specific reason for using apim resource twice in the same configuration @H.Pauwelyn?

https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/10538 check with this once @H.Pauwelyn

@VinayB there is not a real reason why I've the same APIM defined twice. It just compiles. Thanks also for the link to GitHub. I'll find a workaround using two bicep files as explained on GitHub.
